# How to open view pass parameter in mvc 4?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I don't known how to open a view pass parameter via a function javascript. Example : open a view DetailProduct with pass parameter categoryid and productid

```
       function DetailProduct(cid, pid) {
        window.location.replace('@Url.Action("Detail", "Product", new { CategoryID = cid , ProductID = pid })');
    }
```

I get error `The name cid does not exist in the current context`  and `The name pid does not exist in the current context`
Thank so much.

Comment: Can yout post the code of the corresponding action in your controller ?

Comment: `@Html.Action()` is razor code and is evaluated on the server before its passed to the view. `cid` and `pid` are javascript variables which do not even exist at that point. You cannot add them as route parameters. You need to manually generate the url = e.g. `'@Url.Action("Detail", "Product")' + '?CategoryID=" + cid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Url.Action` is executed on server when view is rendered while `cid` and `pid` are client side variables so they technically don't exist on server.

if `CategoryID` and `ProductID` are optional parameters in your action:

```
public ActionResult Product(int? CategoryID, int? ProductID)
```

then you can do something like

```
var url =  '@Url.Action("Detail", "Product")' + '?CategoryID=' + cid + "&ProductID=" + pid
```

You can also create a specific user friendly url for this action. Inside `RouteConfig.cs`file add a route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ProductDetails",
                url: "/Detail/Product/{CategoryID}/{ProductID}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Detail", action = "Product", CategoryID = UrlParameter.Optional, ProductID = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

then you will be able to create a url like this:

```
var url =  '@Url.Action("Detail", "Product")' + '/' + cid + "/" + pid;
```

which will eventually look like `http://.../Product/Detail/1/2` for `cid = 1` and `pid=2`